# AWS EC2 - MySQL Event Scheduler Not Starting on Server Restart With Event_Scheduler = ON

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, my.cnf

I currently have

```
event_scheduler = ON
```

in my `my.cnf` file on my EC2 instance at `/etc/my.cnf`

If the MySQL instance restarts, the event scheduler does not start up automatically.

What could be preventing the event scheduler from starting automatically?

Is there a way to check if another `my.cnf` file is overwriting the one at `/etc/my.cnf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event_scheduler = ON` was underneath the `[mysqld_safe]` section.  The event scheduler auto-starts after it was moved to underneath the `[mysqld]` section.